# Google Dataflow SQL | Creating Branches | Error Handling

Tags: sql, google-cloud-dataflow

Trying to use Dataflow SQL for Stream ingestion:

We have a Pubsub topic (source) and BigQuery Table (sink).

To achieve that we need to follow steps:

1. From BigQuery UI, adding schema for topic manually.

   Question: **Can we automate this process using commandline options?**
2. Writing SQL for the transformation and executing using `gcloud dataflow query` command (helps us with dynamic queries and automation).

   Question: Suppose we have missing key from Pubsub messages and the pipeline will mark those messages as error in stack driver. **Can we add some capability like if validation of schema fails move to table `y` else table `x`? Something like, if we get message type `y` move of table `y` else table `x`?**

Comment: For question 2: I found a workaround using log sink to dump only error message to a bigquery table:  `gcloud logging sinks create dump_table dataset _info  --log-filter='resource.type="dataflow_step" AND resource.labels.job_id="id" AND logName=("projects/p_id/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fjob-message" OR "projects/p_id/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Flauncher") AND severity="ERROR"'` check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/sinks/create)

Comment: You may want to ask the questions separately so they can have clearer answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gcloud` to add a schema to a topic. This was actually the only way to do it, at first: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/data-sources-destinations#gcloud

For saving messages that cannot be parsed into SQL rows, the functionality is often called "dead letter queue". It is available in Beam SQL DDL for Pubsub but is not yet available when using Dataflow SQL through the BigQuery UI. See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/extensions/create-external-table/#pubsub

Comment: Schema definition works in different way for catalog commands,  name --> column ; fields --> subcolumns here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.datacatalog.v1beta1#columnschema)